Divergence expression in a Riemannian manifold
I have the following Euler-Lagrange equation of a functional in a Riemannian manifold $M$:
$$\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\phi'(|\nabla u|)}{|\nabla u|} \nabla u\right) = 0.$$
How can I express that as
$$\frac{\phi'(|\nabla u|)}{|\nabla u|} \Delta u + \frac{A(|\nabla u|)}{|\nabla u|}\nabla^{2}u(\nabla u, \nabla u) = 0,$$
where $A(|\nabla u|) = \phi''(|\nabla u|)/|\nabla u| - \phi'(|\nabla u|)/|\nabla u|^{2}$? If we were in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, I could see this as an immediate application of the product rule for divergence, but in the Riemmanian case, I am a bit lost, especially when trying to recover the bilinear form associated with the Hessian $\nabla^{2}$ and $A(|\nabla u|)$.

Do you have any formula for divergence?

@ArcticChar I don't, but I presume it is similar to the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case. Namely, $\operatorname{div}\psi F = \psi \operatorname{div}F + g(\nabla \psi, F)$, where $F \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, $\psi$ is a real-valued function and $g$ is the Riemannian metric. I just want to see a derivation of this, you don't have to prove every formula you use (in case you want to answer the question).

I believe I figured it out. Let $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. Then, we have
$$X(\phi'(|\nabla u|)/|\nabla u|) = \frac{\phi''(|\nabla u|)}{2|\nabla u|^{2}} Xg(\nabla u, \nabla u)-\frac{\phi'(|\nabla u|)}{2|\nabla u|^{3}}X g(\nabla u, \nabla u).$$
Using metric compatibility, the right-hand side can be expressed as
$$2\left(\frac{\phi''(|\nabla u|)}{2|\nabla u|^{2}}-\frac{\phi'(|\nabla u|)}{2|\nabla u|^{3}}\right)g(\nabla_X\nabla u, \nabla u).$$
Recognizing that $g(\nabla_X\nabla u, \nabla u) = \nabla^{2}u(X, \nabla u)$, we obtain
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\phi'(|\nabla u|)}{|\nabla u|} \nabla u\right) &= \frac{\phi'(|\nabla u|)}{|\nabla u|} \Delta u + g(\nabla\phi'(|\nabla u|)/|\nabla u|,\nabla u)
\\&= \frac{\phi'(|\nabla u|)}{|\nabla u|} \Delta u + \frac{A(|\nabla u|)}{|\nabla u|} \nabla^{2} u(\nabla u, \nabla u),
\end{align}$$
where $A$ is as defined earlier.
